# How can I prevent time series data from overlapping?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, graph

I plotted ( x - datetime, y - energy data: 1 t0 1 correspondent data) on the graph by using plt.plot with data over 100000 rows.
But the graph seems to have multiple energy values at one time point.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZd60.jpg)
But if I deal with much less data like 1000 rows,
the graph shows a normal time series graph. (one-to-one correspondence graph)

I want to deal with 100000 rows and get a normal time series graph.
Can you tell me the problem?

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(50,25))

plt.xticks(fontsize=30)

plt.plot(x_df\['day'\], x_df\['energy'\])
```

Comment: Have you checked the `day` column? It should be datetime. Try `x_df.info()` to see if the column is datetime and make sure the format is correct -> dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy..

Comment: Looking at your graph, I'd bet  that you have 11 **different** data series.  Try `plt.plot(x_df['day'], x_df['energy'].reshape(-1, 11))`. NB I don't know if a dataframe "column" can be reshaped, just a guess, but I think that you must reshape

Comment: 11 data series because I can count 10 straight lines running from max(t) to min(t).

Comment: Thank you everybody. I solved it and the problem was data contained many time series so it was not in correct format. Reshaping and editing time format helped. Thank you again